# Image not set Proper After Radius

Tags: android

I have one layout which have two ImageView. And set Radius for corner at runtime on that imageView (work Proper). But After set Radius when i set Image on ImageView(Choose from gallery) it display in Square Shape. Why Radius not apply on my selected image. Set Radius at runtime like this.,

```
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.back_image);
        GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = (GradientDrawable) layerDrawable
                .findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.gradientDrawble);
        gradientDrawable.setCornerRadius(70);

        image1.setBackground(layerDrawable);
        image2.setBackground(layerDrawable);
```

back_image.xml

```
<item android:id="@+id/gradientDrawble">

    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="@color/lightGrey"/>
        <corners android:radius="0dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />
</item>
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPuhP.png)

Comment: Are you using any image loader library to display image in imageview?

Comment: @Divya Chavada see my answer hope this will help you out.

Comment: @AndyDeveloper  thank you.  but it doesn't work for me.:(

Comment: No. i m not use any library @Beena.

Comment: @DivyaChavada what problem you are facing with this RoundedBitmapDrawable?

Comment: It affected only on selected image not apply on my full ImageView background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i suppose you want imageview with corner radius so you can achieve this using [this library](https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView)
>
> here is snippet

```
<com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:src="@drawable/photo1"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:riv_corner_radius="30dip"
    app:riv_border_width="2dip"
    app:riv_border_color="#333333"
    app:riv_mutate_background="true"
    app:riv_tile_mode="repeat"
    app:riv_oval="true" />
```

> or you can use this custom class

```html
public class RoundedImageView extends ImageView {
    private Path mMaskPath;
    private Paint mMaskPaint    = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    private int mCornerRadius   = 10;

    public RoundedImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        init(context);
    }

    public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);

        init(context);
    }

    public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        ViewCompat.setLayerType(this, ViewCompat.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        mMaskPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        mMaskPaint.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));

        mCornerRadius = (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.image_border_curvature);
    }

    /**
     * Set the corner radius to use for the RoundedRectangle.
     */
    public void setCornerRadius(int cornerRadius) {
        mCornerRadius = cornerRadius;
        generateMaskPath(getWidth(), getHeight());
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldW, int oldH) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldW, oldH);

        if (w != oldW || h != oldH) {
            generateMaskPath(w, h);
        }
    }

    private void generateMaskPath(int w, int h) {
        mMaskPath = new Path();
        mMaskPath.addRoundRect(new RectF(0,0,w,h), mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius, Path.Direction.CW);
        mMaskPath.setFillType(Path.FillType.INVERSE_WINDING);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if(canvas.isOpaque()) { // If canvas is opaque, make it transparent
            canvas.saveLayerAlpha(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), 255, Canvas.HAS_ALPHA_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG);
        }

        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if(mMaskPath != null) {
            canvas.drawPath(mMaskPath, mMaskPaint);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But i dont want to use any customView.

Answer (score 0):

Try this short code it don't required any library and work like a charm.

```
RoundedBitmapDrawable roundedBitmapDrawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(Activity.this.getResources(), yourbitmap);
roundedBitmapDrawable.setCornerRadius(setYourOwnRadius);
roundedBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);
your imageview.setImageDrawable(roundedBitmapDrawable);
```